# treeview expanding all elements that have children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar that has children on certain li elements, I have written some code in jQuery that should target each method, yet when I click on the list element, it slidetoggles all that have children.

my code:-

```
//dropdown toggle on treeview
const hasTree  = $('.has-treeview'),
      treeView = $('.nav-treeview');  

$.each(hasTree,function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(treeView).slideToggle();
        });
});
```

and my html;

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">

                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-treeview" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                        <p>
                            Charts
                            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>ChartJS</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Flot</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="p#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Inline</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-tree"></i>
                        <p>
                            UI Elements
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>General</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Icons</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Buttons</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Sliders</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-edit"></i>
                        <p>
                            Forms
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>General Elements</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Advanced Elements</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Editors</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-table"></i>
                        <p>
                            Tables
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Simple Tables</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Data Tables</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-header">EXAMPLES</li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <p>
                            Calendar
                            <span class="badge badge-info right">2</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <p>
                            Mailbox
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Inbox</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Compose</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Read</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
                        <p>
                            Pages
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Invoice</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Profile</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Login</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Register</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Lockscreen</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                        <p>
                            Extras
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Error 404</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Error 500</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Blank Page</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                                <p>Starter Page</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-header">MISCELLANEOUS</li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-file"></i>
                        <p>Documentation</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-header">LABELS</li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-danger"></i>
                        <p class="text">Important</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-warning"></i>
                        <p>Warning</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-info"></i>
                        <p>Informational</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

so basically I just want to expand the treeview for the one that was clicked, not all of them. Where am I going wrong?

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/661999/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//dropdown toggle on treeview
const hasTree  = $('.has-treeview');

$.each(hasTree,function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).children('.nav-treeview').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/662108/)

Comment: Thankyou, you got it! I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
//dropdown toggle on treeview
const hasTree  = $('.has-treeview'),
treeView = $('.nav-treeview');  
$(hasTree).click(function(){
   $(this).find('.nav-treeview').slideToggle();
});
```

Only add listeners to elements with hasTree classes and than find their treeview and toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

Change only data-accordion from false to true!
Change from:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
```

to

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="true">
```